# Will pressure treated wood with moisture damage regular framed wood in interior wall usage? Asking cause im framing a wall and noticed the moisture?

Tags: framing

I have pressure treated wood to frame a  bathroom wall in a shed and it has quite a bit of moisture in it. I'm concerned about matching it up to standard framing wood and flooring plywood & asking for advice if there's anything to worry about with moisture or do I need a type of vapor barrier?

Comment: probably confusing the pressure treated liquid with moisture

Answer (score 1):

The only concern with using pressure treated (PT) lumber adjacent to framing is the type of fasteners to use. Non galvanized nails will rust terribly, and in the worst case fail because of the excess moisture.

You will need to use nails that are approved to be used in PT lumber, so corrosion does not occur, otherwise the moisture in the PT lumber will dry out over time and be of no concern, especially in a shed where the air moves more freely than in a home.

FWIW, I have seen non approved nails used in PT lumber in bottom plates during the demo of drywall and other remodels, and the rust is apparent but not detrimental, since the PT wood had dried out. The main culprit is the water, it is the catalyst for corrosion, after it dries it lessens the effects of corrosion. In your case, since it is a shed, do use galvanized nails. Humidity may be a factor in that. Also, I do not let my observations change what nails I use in PT lumber. It is simply info.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure-treated wood is kept moist deliberately and is almost always sold that way.

> I'm concerned about matching it up to standard framing wood and flooring plywood

The moisture will eventually evaporate and the wood will be as dry as normal, untreated wood. Vapor barriers are to prevent outside moisture from coming in.

Comment: Keeping the PT wood wet deliberately is news to me... what is your take on why that is? I alway thought it was part of the PT process and was not kiln dried again for cost purposes. After all, it eventually does dry out as in the case of using it in basements as bottom plates, and other places.

Comment: @Jack Might depend on the store you use. PT comes out wet, and is typically shipped that way. Some places keep it so to limit warping

Comment: Would love a citation. I’d always thought they were swamp bottom weight to save manufacturing dollars.

Comment: Keeping the PT wood wet will keep it from warping. Good for the seller, bad for the buyer when it twists up. Not all PT does, but it does have a reputation. As long as a house sets on it by the time it dries, it will stay flat then by-cracky...